# Highlighting keywords in JTextArea (Netbeans)

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, syntax-highlighting, jtextarea

I'm using a text area in Netbeans(Java), and I want to highlight certain keywords in the text, something like syntax-highlighting in programming. How could I do that but within a JTextArea in Netbeans?

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26986778/compare-two-strings-and-highlight-the-mismatch-wherever-found/26987044#26987044)

Answer (score 3):

You can't use a JTextArea to highlight individual pieces of text.

I would suggest a `JTextPane` so you can use styled attributes.

The basic code would be something like:

```
JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
textPane.setText( "one\ntwo\nthree\nfour\nfive\nsix\nseven\neight" );
StyledDocument doc = textPane.getStyledDocument();

//  Define a keyword attribute

SimpleAttributeSet keyWord = new SimpleAttributeSet();
StyleConstants.setForeground(keyWord, Color.RED);
StyleConstants.setBackground(keyWord, Color.YELLOW);

//  Change attributes on some text

doc.setCharacterAttributes(0, 5, keyWord, false);
```